# SQL: multiple execution

Tags: mysql

I need some help . I have this command in mysql

```
  SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 200000
```

and

```
  SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
   WHERE table_schema = 'updates_temp' AND 
         table_name LIKE 'mg_%';" -s
```

how can I make it as one command .

Since I have error in

```
 mg_=`mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 200000 SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'updates_temp' AND table_name LIKE 'mg_%';" -s`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a **;**

```
mg_=`mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 200000; SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'updates_temp' AND table_name LIKE 'mg_%';" -s`
```